# Can we have a .cs file in a namespace , but without a class?

Tags: c#, class

in a C# assembly, can we have a file for example  File1.cs that is in the same namespace as that assembly but it does Not have a class?
so for example something like this:

```
namespace something.otherthing
{
  public enum E1
  { ..... }

  public enum E2
  { ...  }  
}
```

I think this should be Wrong?  but we could do that in VB 6.0 but in C# every thing should be a class.
wanted to make sure .

Comment: I'm sorry but a -1 for not actually testing this out first.

Comment: +1 question is clear... may be it can be answered by investigating or reading a little bit but is still a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File names have nothing to do with namespaces. Any namespace that's at the top of the file is where the enums are, so if that's `something.otherthing` the enums are available with `something.otherthing.E1`. You can have multiple classes in one file, you can have part of a class in a file, you can have no classes at all in a file, you can have enums with classes in a file, etc. Files are just for you, they don't *mean* anything.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that's perfectly legal C# code.

Could you not have tested it out for yourself?

Comment: then how can we have access to for example E1?- did not work for me in a project - 
namespace.FileName.E1 ??? - did not work!

Comment: It's actually `something.otherthing.E1`. C# is case sensitive :)

Comment: I just have a habit of CamelCasing namespaces and classes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

You may only declare the following outside a class...

class, enum, delegate, interface or struct.

Everything else must be in a class.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace can contain `Type` definitions. `Type`s are derived from `class`, `struct` and  `enum`. `interface` and `delegate` are definitions of `Type` declarations.

As previously mentioned a namespace can be empty.